# How to make UITableView Header selectable?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have made a custom section-header for UITableView, that includes some controls like segmented control, UIImageView ,etc. It successfully appears, but it's not tappable so I can't interact with its controls.

I need to know how can I make this header view selectable?

Comment: if you are using ImageView as base view then use imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Answer (score 30):

There is no way to do it with the **UITableViewDelegate.**

You have to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to yourHeaderView Like:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureHandler:)];
[singleTapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
singleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
singleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;   
[yourHeaderView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapRecognizer];


-(void) handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer; //do in this method whatever you want
```

**FOR Swift 3.0**

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YOURVIEWCONTROLLER.TapGestureRecognizer(_:)))
yourHeaderView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

func TapGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    //do your stuff here 
}
```

**Swift  >= 4.0**

Add **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate**  class reference inherited

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
tap.delegate = self
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

  @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //Do your work 
    }
```

may be it will help.

Happy Coding.

Comment: if there was more than 1 section in screen (dose not need to scroll) tap on all sections act same.

Comment: Just a quick note: `.numberOfTouchesRequired` and `.numberOfTapsRequired` are by default set to 1, so you don't need to manually set them unless it's something other than 1.

Comment: Swift >= 5: There is no need for adding a delegate property to "tap" anymore.

Answer (score 9):

Here is what worked for me:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let v = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()
    v.textLabel?.text = "Header Text"
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    tapRecognizer.delegate = self
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    v.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    return v
}

func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    print("Tapped")
}
```

Comment: beware that if you use `tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView` to recycle an existing view instead of creating a new one every time you need to ensure that you don't repeatedly add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` over and over.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to know the index of the tapped section, you can use the following pattern (**Swift 4**) :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 44))

    // Configure your view here
    // ...

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
        target: self,
        action: #selector(headerTapped(_:))
    )
    view.tag = section
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    return view
}

@objc func headerTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
    guard let section = sender?.view?.tag else { return }

    // Use your section index here
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest way, in my experience too.. Thanks..

Answer (score 4):

Simple drop in solution for Swift 3.0

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let v = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        v.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
        return v
    }


    func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
    {
        controller?.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom section headerView.. and then add Tap gesture to it.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

//This method will be called on Tap of section header
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
//Do the action on Tap
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add a UIButton to your header view (or your header view can be a  UIButton itself).

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    UIButton *cellButton = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    [cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(premiumSectionClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender{

}
```

Comment: The most simple solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom view used as section head view and implement the method
`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`, it will be called when your finger tap on it.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Easiest way to add a touch event on a header View

Answer (score 1):

My implementation in Swift:

In your `UITableViewController`:

```
let myView = MyView()

let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: myView, action: "handleTap")
myView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myView
```

In `MyView`:

```
class MyView: UIView {

    func handleTap() {
        // Handle touch event here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

swift solution for this:

```
let tapR : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "gotoHeaderArticle")
tapR.delegate = self
tapR.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
tapR.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
yourView.addGestureRecognizer(tapR)
```

Then implement

```
func gotoHeaderArticle() {

}
```

Make sure to make your calling viewcontroller adhere to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

Answer (score 0):

Update for Swift 3.1

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TapGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer:)))
yourView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

func TapGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        //do your stuff here
        print("Gesture")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me

```
  -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    YourHeaderTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   cell.imageView.image = [image imageNamed:@"imageName"];
cell.segmentedControl.tag = section;
[cell.segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(action:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    return cell;
}

- (void)action:(id)sender{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
    NSLog(@"selected section:%ld",(long)segmentedControl.tag);

}
```

Comment: This will break if you have updates to your table during runtime. If e.g. a section is inserted at the beginning of the table (using beginUpdates endUpdates), then the existing sections headers won't get reloaded and the tags will contain wrong section indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs a solution that can work when the tableview has multiple sections, I had the same problem and the solution I came up with was to create different targets on a button at the `viewForHeaderInSection` method, based on the section. I am using a button but this should work just as well with UITapGestureRecognizer

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        // ...

        if section == 0 {
            cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(firstSectionTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        } else if section == 1 {
            cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(secondSectionTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }

        // ...

}
```

Then in the ViewController:

```
@objc func goalCategoryTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
    print("Section One Tapped")
}

@objc func ideaCategoryTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
    print("Section Two Tapped")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on hkdalex answer, this solution works for me.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            
        let sectionHeaderBackgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.921, saturation: 0.34, brightness: 0.94, alpha: 0.4)
            
        let sectionHeaderLabelView = UIView()
        sectionHeaderLabelView.backgroundColor = sectionHeaderBackgroundColor
            
        let sectionHeaderImage = UIImage(named: "alimentation")
        let sectionHeaderImageView = UIImageView(image: sectionHeaderImage)
        sectionHeaderImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 3, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30)
        sectionHeaderLabelView.addSubview(sectionHeaderImageView)
            
        let sectionHeaderLabel = UILabel()
        sectionHeaderLabel.text = self.alimCategories[section].nom//sectionHeaderTitles[section]
        sectionHeaderLabel.textColor = .brown
        sectionHeaderLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
        sectionHeaderLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 43, y: 5, width: 250, height: 40)
        sectionHeaderLabelView.addSubview(sectionHeaderLabel)
        
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sectionHeaderTapped))
        tapRecognizer.delegate = self
        tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        self.selectedHeaderName = self.alimCategories[section].nom
        sectionHeaderLabelView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
        
        return sectionHeaderLabelView
            
    }
    
    @objc func sectionHeaderTapped(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
    {
        let headerText = self.selectedHeaderName
        print(headerText! + " tapped")
    }
```

With this code you can customize the section header with header image and text, attach a tap listener and get the selected text from a global variable.