# Tapping on section(Height 400.0f) View of UITableview calls didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have UITableview with a section whose height is 400 and when I scroll down and tap on section View then it calls didSelectionRowAtIndexPath. So how can I detect/identify that it is section view?

Comment: if you are talking about section header check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19999488/653513

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply you can add UIButton or UITapGestureRecognizer on section view and create your own listener method. then didSelectRowAtIndexPath method not called

Answer (score 0):

you can not tap section, you can tap rows in that section.

If you have more than one section and you want to apply different logic for both the section than add,

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    switch(section){
       case 0:
       return [array count];
       break;
       case 1:
       return [array count];
       break;
    }
}
```

So it calls only RowsInSection.

Comment: I know I can't tap on section view utile we add gesture or any action. But I have section view (400 height) and when i tap on that then it action on cell.