# Clickable UITableView section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a sectioned UITableView. Rather than have each row of the section individually selectable, how to I make it so the entire section (rows plus header view) respond the same if there is a tap anywhere in the section. Suggestions?

Comment: There's no support for this in UITableView. It's not really needed. It's easy enough to add your own tap gesture to your section header view and of course the table already supports selecting a row. Simply have all of those handlers call a common function as needed.

Comment: Is there a way so that when I press on the header view that i can give some sort of feedback for the entire section i.e. changing the background color for the header view and all the rows if the header view or any row in the section is being pressed?

Comment: @DANGERZONE94 My answer gives you a good template for doing that. If you need help changing the background color of a header view and its rows when you tap, try doing it on your own and then put that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of behavior can be supported in different ways. The simplest way to make an entire section have the same behavior is as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            doBehavior0()
            break
        case 1:
            doBehavior1()
            break
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this will not work for headers. You'll have to create a gesture recognizer and call `doBehaviorX()` from that. [More details here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996566/how-to-make-uitableview-header-selectable) This should be simple enough to implement if you have a fixed number of sections (which I will assume since your question didn't specify).